# How do you hide an item when button is selected?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to hide image, instructions and name when a user selects a button.
When a user selects the 'complete' button, I want just that item associated with the button to disappear.

See my code for how items are being displayed below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($daysLeft == 7)){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Profile SET Points=:points WHERE UserID=$UserID");
    $stmt->execute();
    //need something here to hide whats displayed
    echo "Well done!";
}else {
}
```

Code which is displaying each item:

```
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "" . $dbRow["Name"] . "</h4><br>" . "<br><img src=\" . $dbRow['Picture'] . "' width='150' height='150' />" . "<br><br>" . $dbRow["Instructions"] . "<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete'>";
}
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: your question is unclear. please try and add more details so we can understand what you need help with

Comment: Use jQuery property => jQuery('#DivId').hide(); on submit event. *DivId= you can specify any element id or class name here.

Comment: @thatkookooguy Basically, what is currently being displayed is lots of different items for the user...there are buttons beside each one, and when they 'SELECT' the button, i want that ITEM to disappear? Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer am i not able to use PHP to hide it or anything?

Comment: @Ellen PHP is server side, it has no interaction with the browser/client. The PDO code also is pseudo? The prepared statement is incorrect for 2 reasons (1 no binding, 2 variable in the statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you're re-loading the page then you could do it with PHP.

Where you've put the comment
`//need something here to hide whats displayed` you could set a variable, e.g. `$hide = true`. Make sure it's initialised beforehand, `$hide = false`, outside of the `if` statement:

```
$hide = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($daysLeft == 7)){
    // existing code
    $hide = true;
}
```

If `$hide` is still `false`, you show can the image:

```
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "" . $dbRow["Name"] . "</h4><br>" . "<br>";

    if ($hide) {
        echo "<img src=\" . $dbRow['Picture'] . "' width='150' height='150' />";
    }

    echo "<br><br>" . $dbRow["Instructions"] . "<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete'>";
}
```

If you're *not* reloading the page, a JavaScript/jquery solution is better. But since you've tagged it with PHP I'm assuming you will be doing a page reload.

**Incidentally, the HTML on this looks awful.** You've closed a `<h4>` tag that isn't open, for example. However I've copied your markup as-is so you can see where it fits in. A cleaner version of the markup:

```
echo "<h4>" . $dbRow["Name"] . "</h4><br>";

if (!$hide) {
    echo "<img src='" . $dbRow['Picture'] . "' width='150' height='150'>";
}

echo "<br><br>" . $dbRow["Instructions"] . "<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete'></form>";
```

You also shouldn't really be using `<br>` tags to space things out, but that's a separate concern...

Comment: thanks very much for this. I have tried it, but it doesn't seem to be hiding anything? And i know its off topic, but what else is good for line breaks instead of <br> (i am a beginner as you can tell) @Andy

Comment: @Ellen My mistake - I've edited the answer. It should have said `if ($hide)` - it previously said `if (!$hide)` (the `!` means it's checking if `$hide` is `false`, when it should have been updated to `true` if the logic had been applied correctly). For the spacing - you should look up a good CSS tutorial and use things like `<div>` tags with margins/padding.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Javascript to do that. Try putting the elements that you want to hide in a div, and then change their css visibility property to none on the click() Javascript event.

Comment: do you mean like this? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that this will include jquery too.